# Show that if $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and all its $\mathbb{C}$-derivatives vanish in one point then $f$ is identicaly zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to show that if an analytic function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (where $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open and convex set) and all its $\mathbb{C}$-derivatives vanish in one point $z_0 \in U$ then $f$ is identicaly zero.

Because $f$ is analytic on $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, we can expand it in a power serie,
\begin{equation}
  f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z - z_0)^n, \quad \forall z_0 \in U
\end{equation}

But from there, I was thinking about Liouville theorem. If I could show that $f$ was bounded then with the equivalence analytic $\leftrightarrow$ holomorphic, $f$ would be constant on $U$ and because $f$ vanish in $z_0 \in U$ it would vanish in all $z \in U$.

Does that make sense ?
If yes, how could I find a bound ?

Comment: If all derivaties are zero at some point $z_0$ then there is some small ball in which $f$ is identically zero. Then the identify theorem shows that it is zero in $U$ (since it is connected).

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)$ is assumed analytic and all the derivatives of which vanish, then $f(z)$ vanishes at every point within an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. However, the zero set of an analytic function is made up of isolated points. Therefore, $f(z)$ must be identically zero.

For a more direct proof, let $V:=\{z\in U\,|\, f^n(z)=0\,,\, \forall\, n\geq0\}$. V is non-empty by assumption. We will prove that $V$ is both open and closed, which will imply that $V=U$. To see that $V$ is closed, note that any limit point of $V$ that lies in $U$ must also lie in $V$ since $f^n(z)$ is continuous for all $n\geq 0$. Note further that $V$ is open because if we take $z_0\in V$, $f(z)$ is assumed analytic and hence has a convergent power series inside a disk contained in $U$ expanded about the point $z_0$. However, $f(z)$ is the zero function inside of this disk, hence the disk is contained in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

An outline of a proof might go as follows:

Pick another arbitrary point, say $z_1 \in \Omega$. Define $\gamma: [0,1] \to \Omega$ by $\gamma(t) = (1-t)z_0 + tz_1$; convexity guarantees that this is possible. If you define $S = \{t \in [0,1] : f^{(k)}(\gamma(t)) = 0 \text{ for all } k \geq 0\}$, you can then prove that $\sup S = 1$.

An alternative which would work on a more general domain would be to consider $A = \{z \in \Omega: f^{(k)}(z) = 0 \text{ for all } k \geq 0\}$. By using power series expansion, you should be able to prove that $A$ is open in $\Omega$. But, by continuity, $A$ is closed in $\Omega$, from which it follows that $A = \Omega$.

Comment: I hadn't seen this first method before; it's kind of cool. I guess the idea is to "analytically continue" the zeros via continuity and small increments in $t$?